# Run PHP script in background using GET request to avoid timeout

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a `php` script which downloads a CSV file and updates stock for products on PrestaShop.

The problem is that this script can be executed only through GET request but there is some timeout on the server-side which causes an error.

I can't increase the timeout so I have to figure out a workaround.

My idea is to make this script run the import snippet in the background (in another process) so the script will end almost immediately (eg. no timeout), but the `import` will run in the background.

Is it possible?

My script:

```
<?php
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php');


$url = 'URL';

$file_name = basename($url);

if(file_put_contents( $file_name,file_get_contents($url))) {
    echo "File downloaded successfully";
}
else {
    echo "File downloading failed.";
   // die('error');
}
echo  "\n";
echo "<br>";

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {

        // skip first ligne (header  csv )
        if ($row == 1 || $row == 2) {
               continue;
        }

        if(!($data[5] == 'Suk' || $data[5] == 'plus size')){
               continue;
        }
        // get attribut from prestashop database 
        if(empty($data[9]))
            continue;


        $productAttribut=findProductAttributByReference($data[9]);

        // if product attribut exist
        if(!empty($productAttribut)){
        echo $productAttribut['id_product_attribute'];
            // update quantity

                StockAvailable::setQuantity((int)$productAttribut['id_product'],(int)$productAttribut['id_product_attribute'], (int)$data[10], Context::getContext()->shop->id);
                echo  "product  ".$productAttribut['id_product_attribute']."  quantity \n updated";
                echo  "\n";
                echo "<br>";
        }


    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
  echo  "\n";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "end script ";
}


function findProductAttributByReference($reference){

$sql='
            SELECT *
            FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute`
            WHERE `reference` = "' . $reference.'"'
        ;
    $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql);
         return $result;
}
  
?>
```

Comment: While your PHP isn't running in safe_mode you can try this at the beginning of your script: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: PHP is blocking, which mean that a block of code will not run until the previous block has finished. To do that, your task must be "asynchronous". I'm not an expert of Asynchronous PHP. I'll let you search more on the web and SO about asynchronous PHP.

Comment: Instead of using `fgetcsv` you can try opening it as a stream and write code to download it in chunks while keeping track of the time in your loop. That is, in multiple GETs via ajax if at all possible with prestashop. The actual csv file can be saved server-side and manipulated after the last chunk, server-side.

Comment: Actually timeout is kind of implemented by server software like `Apache` / `Nginx`. Why not use cron job to run the file using command line `php`.

Comment: Or within your .htaccess: `php_value max_execution_time 9999`

Comment: @biesior Thanks, I'm trying your first advice and it seems to be running longer than 600 seconds. If it doesn't work, I'll try the second advice.

Comment: You can check both using simple `<?php phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

**No you can't**,

As `@martin Paucot` said in comment, PHP is blocking. It will run all the instructions one by one. meanwhile, Each instruction will be waiting previous one to be finished.

So, Your main script will be waiting for your imported script to finish its execution.

**Possible Way**

Use `CRON Job` to export `CSV` in background and push a notification once it's job completed. So user will be notified once the job completed and download the file using a link. *(You will need to store some records in database)*